# Realizar una Calculadora en Netbeans con JOptionPane

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2, java-util-scanner

### Calculadora Básica con JOptionPane

Buenas, necesito ayuda, en clase me pasaron el codigo de una calculadora sencilla. 
En resumen, me pidieron que en vez de usar **system.out.println** lo remplaze con **JOptionPane** 
Hice los cambios en el codigo reemplazando todos los system por JOptionPane pero al momento de correr el programa solamente muestra el primer JOptionPane, de allí el programa continua corriendo pero se queda en RUN y no continua.
El programa en que estoy haciendo el código es Netbeans 8.2 IDE.
Es de las primeras veces que estoy haciendo código
Agradecería mucho la ayuda, muchas gracias.

```
package calculadora;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Calculadora_Pane {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double res = 0;
    String operacion;
    boolean comprobar = false;

    do{

        String numero1;
        do {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\n Por favor, dame el primer número de la operación. ");
            numero1 = sc.nextLine();
        } while (!numero1.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
        double nume1 = Double.parseDouble(numero1);
        double n1 = new Double(numero1);

        do {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Teniendo en cuenta que: n + = sumar \n - = restar \n"
                    + " x = multiplicar \n / = dividir \n * = elevar primer número al segundo numero."
                    + "\n % = residuo");
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\n ¿Que operación desea hacer? (Solo coloque un signo)");
        operacion = sc.nextLine();
            if (operacion.equals("+") || operacion.equals("-") || operacion.equals("x") ||
                operacion.equals("X") || operacion.equals("/") || operacion.equals("%") ||
                operacion.equals("*")) {
                comprobar = true;
            }else { comprobar = false; }
        } while (comprobar != true);

        String numero2;
        do {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\n Por favor, dame el segundo número.");
            numero2 = sc.nextLine();
        } while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
        double nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
        double n2 = new Double(numero2);

        do{
            comprobar = true;
            switch(operacion){
                case "+":
                    res = n1 + n2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    res = n1 - n2;
                    break;
                case "x":
                case "X":
                    res = n1 * n2;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    while(n2 == 0){
                             do {
                                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " En el denominador se encuentra \n"
                                        + "un cero, para evitar errores coloca otro número.");
                                numero2 = sc.nextLine();
                            }while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
                                nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
                                n2 = new Double(numero2);
                    }
                    res = n1 / n2;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    res = Math.pow(n1, n2);
                    break;
                case "%":
                    while(n2 == 0){
                             do {
                                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " En el denominador se encuentra \n"
                                        + "un cero, para evitar errores coloca otro número.");
                                numero2 = sc.nextLine();
                            }while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
                                nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
                                n2 = new Double(numero2);
                    }
                    res = n1 % n2;
                    break;
            }
        }while(comprobar != true);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "(" + numero1 + ") " + operacion + " (" + numero2 + ")" + " = " + res);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n ¿Desea hacer alguna otra operación? \n");
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, " [SI / NO]");
        do{
            comprobar = true;
            operacion = sc.nextLine();

            switch (operacion) {
                case "s":
                case "S":
                case "n":
                case "N":
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n Error, ponga un literal valido. \n");
                    comprobar = false;
            }
        }while(comprobar != true);
    }while(operacion.equals("s") || operacion.equals("S"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que si usas `JOptionPane`, ya no necesitas el objeto `Scanner` ni ejecutar `nextLine`, ya que esta función obtiene el resultado de la consola, y no de lo que tecleas en el `JOptionPane`. La función `showInputDialog` retorna el `String` tecleado por el usuario.

Algo como esto:

```
numero1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\n Por favor, dame el primer número de la operación. ");
```

La variable `numero1` tendrá el texto tecleado o cadena vacía en caso de pulsar `Cancel` en el cuadro de diálogo, así que antes de usar la cadena debes comprobar que tiene contenido.